# Inline edit using ng change angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, django, inline-editing

I have a editable table and I reproduce the sum of column values below the table. Now I want to change the column values and the sum of column values below should change automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Update the model for the sum on column change.